# Create variables from list in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create variables based on a list I have.

The list looks something like this:

```
color = c("blue","green","yellow")
```

Each string in the list will become a variable. The variable should take the values based on another column (for example, usercolorlist). Here is the pseudocode:

```
For each row in usercolorlist
   if usercolorlist contains blue
       then blue = 1
       else 0
```

Ultimately, the output would be:

```
usercolorlist blue
"blue/red/green" 1 
"red/green" 0
"blue/red" 1
```

I want to implement this as cleanly as possible. I mainly use python and have been told that for loops are not as efficient in R.

Comment: `sapply(color, function(x) as.numeric(grepl(x, usercolorlist)))`

Comment: @d.b This works. I was able to save it as a dataframe and add it to the original dataset using the following: `colorvariables = sapply(color, function(x) as.numeric(grepl(x, usercolorlist)))                                         finaldata = cbind(usercolorlist,colorvariables)` Is this a valid solution or are there better ways to write this?